# index of substring program code from c to mips

Tags: c++11, mips32

The following is a c++ program that prints the index of the first letter in the substring from the string, need to do it in mips.

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
string s = "my string";
string sub = "rin";
int index=-1;
for(int i=0;i<s.length(); i++){
    if(s[i] == sub[0]){
        index = i;
        for(int j=i+1; j<sub.length(); j++){
            if(s[j] != sub[j]){
                index = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
cout << index;
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Show us what you have attempted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just compile it for MIPS, and it will run on MIPS.